# Is ArcMap compatible with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcmap

I need to make an add-in in ArcMap, that I upload an arcmaps window where a 360 image type PhotoSphereViewer is displayed.
Ref: http://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org/

But when loading in viewer html a page that makes use of this library throws an error.

I would like to know how I can work with JavaScript in ArcMap, or if there is another alternative to present 360 images in ArcMap.

Comment: When you say "ArcMap," do you mean ArcGIS Desktop? Or are you making an ArcGIS map viewer (HTML5)?

Comment: ArcGIS Desktop, I need a windows that show me the pic on 360